# javascript not working in IIS

Tags: c#, javascript, iis

I have page unload javascript that is working fine, but not in IIS ,Do I need to give any permission in IIS for this?Here is my javascript that is not working

```
window.onbeforeunload = InitializeService;
function InitializeService() {
    InitializeService1();
    if (checkdisposition.disposition == "") {
        var agree =   confirm("You Did Not Save Disposition, Are You Sure You Want To Navigate?");
        if (agree) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return "You Did Not Save Disposition ";
        }
    }
}

function InitializeService1() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var url = "http://localhost:54329/WebServices/PageUnloadCall.asmx?op=Page_Unload";
        myReq.onreadystatechange = checkStatus1;
        myReq.open("GET", url, false); // true indicates asynchronous request
        myReq.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: The webserver has nothing to do with client-side scripts. And your indentation is horrible. And you shouldn't `confirm()` or `alert()` inside the unbeforeunload event. Only return a string and let the browser do the prompting. Otherwise your users will get two prompts.

Comment: It's most likely some sort of cross site scripting issue. IIS is just the server. What URL are you browsing to that this code is running on?

Comment: Try using a relative URL on your ajax call

Comment: It is unusual to run JavaScript code in IIS (which is also unlikely your case based on your sample). Please use browser's developer tools (i.e. in IE press F12 and debug script/look at console) to provide better error information for the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. I've written lots of (IIS) ASP code in JavaScript back in the days, but the question is really about client side JavaScript

Comment: Yes... I should have said "...unusual for modern application..." :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your site's Urls for "non IIS case" and "IIS case"? You could be hitting cross domain restriction when opening Web request to "http://localhost:54329" in IIS case (since site would be different (usually http://localhost:80).

Note that as @Juan Mendes pointed out the XMLHttpRequest may not work at all at that time and definitely will not return asynchronous results **before** page finish closing.

Comment: Hi thanks for help you are exactly right,I test it in IE and it gives me error  at line                                                  'myReq.open("GET", url, false);' . Can I solve this?

Comment: To get site's Url either render it from server or use window.location as base or sometimes relative Url works. Note that it is unlikely to help your overall case as it is bad idea to communicate with server around "navigate away".

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers do not allow sending an `XMLHttpRequest` during the `onbeforeunload` handler

Also, you should not display a prompt when handling `onbeforeunload`. You should just return a string if there is unsaved data

From Alexei's answer, my guess is that the real problem is that you were running your page by typing in `localhost` into the URL bar. But when deployed, you're typing the name of the deployed server. Like Alexei suggested, you should not hardcode `localhost` in your code. Since it looks like you wanna do it on the client side, you should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

```
var url = location.host + "/WebServices/PageUnloadCall.asmx?op=Page_Unload";
```

Comment: It could be, but it would work the same irrespective of hosting.

Comment: @Juan Mendes iF that is browser related problem ,Why is it working with local host?

Comment: @Hiren: added a note about what the problem likely is, but it looks like you figured it out